# Bonbons falling continuously from random positions

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have got the following problem in SpriteKit: My aim is to let bonbons fall continuously from the top of the screen. These bonbons can be collected by the player. Every 0.8 seconds or so, another bonbon should fall down and when the player collides with one of the bonbons, it should disappear. This is my code:

```
-(void)populate {

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        [self generate];
    }

}



-(void)generate {

    Y = (arc4random() % 280) - 140;

    bonbon = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Bonbon.png"];
    bonbon.size = CGSizeMake(20, 20);
    bonbon.name = @"bonbon";
    bonbon.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = bonbonCategory;
    bonbon.position = CGPointMake(Y, 500);
    bonbon.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:bonbon.size.width/2];
    bonbon.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    [bonbon addChild:bonbon];


}


-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{


    if ([contact.bodyA.node.name  isEqualToString: @"wallLeft"] || [contact.bodyB.node.name  isEqualToString: @"wallLeft"])
    {

        [hero.physicsBody applyImpulse: CGVectorMake(100, 60)];
        self.jumpDirection = YES;

    }

    else if ([contact.bodyA.node.name isEqualToString: @"bonbon"] || [contact.bodyB.node.name isEqualToString: @"bonbon"])
    {

        [world enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"bonbon" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
            PointsLabel *pointsLabel = (PointsLabel *)[self childNodeWithName:@"pointsLabel"];
            [pointsLabel increment];

            NSLog(@"didContactBonbon");

            [bonbon removeFromParent];

            NSLog(@"removedFromParent");

        }];

    }

    else {

        [hero.physicsBody applyImpulse: CGVectorMake(-100, 60)];
        self.jumpDirection = NO;

    }


}
```

I hope you understand my problem. Currently, no bonbons are falling at all. If you need more information, please do not hesitate to ask.

Greets

edit: I hope the formatting is better now. I am quite a newbie, i'm sorry for foolish mistakes :) This is in my MyScene.m, when is call the populate in the initWithSize method with [self populate]; I receive the message signal SIGABRT. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You get better help when you make it easier for us to help you.  So please format your code properly.  It's easy enough: in Xcode, choose Edit > Select All, then choose Editor > Structure > Re-indent.

Comment: Also, I see methods named `populate` and `generate`, but I don't see any code that calls them (except where `populate` calls `generate`).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are adding your `SKSpriteNode` named `bonbon` to itself with :

```
- (void)generate {
    ...
    bonbon = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Bonbon.png"];
    ...
    [bonbon addChild:bonbon];
}
```

Try to add `bonbon` to your `SKScene` instance.

---

To use an `SKView` instance you have to create a `UIViewController` and give its `view` the `SKView` class. You can do that in your storyboard.

Then, in your viewController :

```
@implementation GameViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;

    // Configure the scene
    SKScene *scene = [SKScene sceneWithSize:self.view.bounds.size];

    // You can add objects to your scene
    [scene addChild:bonbon];

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];
}

@end
```

This is a very simple example but if you want more information, I suggest you read this tutorial: [Sprite Kit Tutorial for Beginners](http://www.raywenderlich.com/42699/spritekit-tutorial-for-beginners).

Comment: I changed it to [SKScene addChild:bonbon]; and I get the error "no known class method for selector 'addChild' "

Comment: It is because there is no class method `+ (void)addChild:` but there is an instance method `- (void)addChild:` so you have to use it with a instance (an object) of `SKScene`, not the class itself. I edited my answer, hope it helps you.